# Take multiple browser snapshots

Tags: selenium, testing

I am an ASP.NET web developer and need to submit artifacts of the developed page, to the testers.

These include:

1. Snapshots of the page when opened in different browsers.
2. Same thing, with different versions of the browsers.

I do this manually (one by one) and also from different systems.(because IE8 is available only at a particular system...so on..). Yes of course time consuming.

Is there a way that could simplify my life in this.(something like browserstack.com)

I am looking at Selenium grid. But this requires some coding too and using eclipse etc. Not sure yet if taking screenshots is possible too and I have no knowledge of selenium.

Appreciate any help in this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Create a config file for the Selenium Hub

The file name should be for example `hubConfig.json` and save it in the same folder where you will start the Hub. The `host` contains the IP of the HUB and the `port` contains the port number ... :)

```
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 4444
}
```

### Run your Selenium Hub, and load the configuration file too

Create a new file with the following name: `startSeleniumHub.cmd` and add the following command in it:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -hubConfig hubconfig.json
```

You can download the latest version Selenium Server Standalone on the Selenium HQ website:

> http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

### Create a config file for the Node

The file name should be for example `nodeConfig.json` and save it in the same folder on the same PC where you will start the Node.

```
{
    "capabilities":[
        {
            "platform":"WINDOWS",
            "browserName":"firefox",
            "firefox_binary":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe",
            "maxInstances":5,
            "seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver"
        },
        {
            "platform":"WINDOWS",
            "browserName":"chrome",
            "maxInstances":5,
            "seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver"
        },
        {
            "platform":"WINDOWS",
            "browserName":"internet explorer",
            "maxInstances":5,
            "version":11,
            "seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver"
        }
    ],
    "configuration":{
        "port":5555,
        "host":"IP_OF_THE_NODE_PC",
        "register":true,
        "hubHost":"IP_OF_THE_HUB",
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "maxSession":1
    }
}
```

If something is not understandable for you in this config, you can read more details about it on the following page:

> https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

If you want, you can add more browsers like Edge, Safari, Opera, etc...

### Connect your PCs to the Selenium Hub as a Node with the configuration file and with the WebDrivers as well

Create a new file with the following name: `startSeleniumNode.cmd` and add the following command in it:

```
java -jar "selenium-server-standalone-X.XX.X.jar" -role node -nodeConfig "nodeConfig.json" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="IEDriverServer.exe"
```

You can download the latest Chrome and IE WebDriver on the same page where you downloaded the Selenium Server Standalone:

> http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

### Write some JAVA code :)

It is just an example, I'm sure that there are better solutions. For example you can use TestNG to create different tests, add parameters to your tests, or run your tests in parallel, etc... You can find more information on the TestNG site: http://testng.org/doc/index.html

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ScreenshotMakerTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        // Init a new DesiredCapabilites which will setup the WebDriver to open a specific browser.
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

        // Set the browser. If you want to open a Chrome, you can modify it to: DesiredCapabilites.chrome(); etc...
        dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        // Set the Platform. It must be the same what you defined in the nodeConfig.json.
        dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

        // Set the version of the browser. If you didn't set any version in the nodeConfig.json, you can skip this line.
        dc.setVersion("11");

        // Create the WebDriver which will open the given browser on a Node
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("IP_OF_THE_HUB:4444/wd/hub"), dc);

        // Open a page
        driver.get("http://google.com");

        // Create screenshot about the current page
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        // Save the screenshot into a file
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\screenshots\\screenshot.png"));

        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

In this example, your code will open an Internet Explorer 11 on a Windows Node, open the `http://google.com` url and create a screenshot about it, and save it to `c:/screenshots/screenshot.png`.

Hope it helps.